# cakephp delete機能について

Tags: php, cakephp

delete機能がうまく動作しません。
エラーメッセージ等は特に出現しないのですが、原因が特定できません。
どなかたアドバイス頂ければ幸いです。

※ `$list` には `$this->Table->find('all');` で取得したデータが格納されています。

**View**

```
<?php echo $this->Html->link('Delete','delete/'.$list['Table']['name'],array(
            'confirm'=>'delete '.$list['Table']['name'].'?'
            ));?>
```

**Controller**

```
public function delete($name=null){
    $data=$this->Table->name=$name;
    $this->Table->delete($data);
    $this->Session->setFlash($data.' was deleted');
    $this->redirect('memberlist');
}
```

Comment: 質問される際は、利用しているCakePHPのバージョンを記述していただけると回答がはかどります。 :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

データを削除する http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/ja/models/deleting-data.html#delete

`delete`メソッドの第一引数は対象モデルのプライマリーキー(一般的には`id`)の値を指定します。

コントローラーのdeleteメソッドの書き方については、こちらを参考にしてください。

ブログチュートリアル - レイヤーの追加 http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/ja/tutorials-and-examples/blog/part-two.html#id6

Comment: なお、例ではGETリクエストで削除できるようですが、これはURLにアクセスするだけで削除が実行されるため、意図しない操作が行われる危険性がありますので、FormHelper::postLinkに置き換えて、コントローラー側では、POSTリクエスト時のみdeleteを実行するようにしたほうが良いでしょう。